# Unable to install 14.04 LTS using USB

Tags: boot

My system configs are mentioned below,

```
Processor: Pentium 4 (2.4 Ghz)
RAM: 2GB
Memory: 40 GB
Motherboard: Intel 915
OS installed: Ubuntu 6.04 dapper LTS
```

I have downloaded 14.04 LTS (intel less then 2 Gb version)with boot in USB stick but when it reaches to Boot from USB stick, it printed a message saying that boot is OK.

But after that it won't go further, I want to know couple of things here.

1. Is there any way to upgrade 6.04 to 14.04 from USB?
2. Is there any compatibility issue with my hardware?
3. I have tried to update through command line but see the below terminal command

outputs.

Please let me know aleast a solution to get rid of this old 6.04 LTS.

From terminal Snapshot:

```
Initializing package states... Done
Building tag database... Done
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B of archives. After unpacking 0B will be used.
ashish@ashish-desktop:~$ sudo aptitude reinstall ubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Initializing package states... Done
Building tag database... Done
The following packages will be REINSTALLED:
  ubuntu-desktop
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B of archives. After unpacking 0B will be used.
Writing extended state information... Error!
E: I wasn't able to locate file for the ubuntu-desktop package. This might mean you need to manually fix this package.
E: Couldn't lock list directory..are you root?
ashish@ashish-desktop:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
sudo: do-release-upgrade: command not found
ashish@ashish-desktop:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 6.06.1 LTS
Release:        6.06
Codename:       dapper
```

Comment: Are you using the 32 bit version of 14.04? Have you created a Live USB using one of the methods described in the Ubuntu web page? Can you try to boot another computer from the Ubuntu 14.04 Live USB and verify that it works there? Please **edit your original question above with additional information.**

Comment: You mentioned "boot in" USB. Does that mean you used unetbootin to make this USB? Last I checked, unetbootin had issues making Ubuntu LiveUSBs. The preferred way to do it is to use [dd](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd) to write the ISO directly to the USB. 6.06 is no longer a supported version and the repository doesn't exist any longer, which would lead to upgrade problems of course. Your only choice to upgrade is to do a fresh install of 14.04.

Comment: An upgrade from 6.04 will not work - it is too old. You need to do a fresh install of 14.04. It sounds like you booted 14.04, but it hung? To debug that, at the boot menu press F6, then replace `splash quiet` with `debug` in the boot parameters and boot. Let us know where it hangs.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you may want to try is:

sudo apt-get update;

sudo apt-get install update-manager-core

**Then** go for:

sudo do-release-upgrade